# Codesign failed with exit code 1 - failing to build copy resources

Tags: ios, code-signing, code-signing-certificate

I realise that this question has been asked quite a few times already, but I have tried to solve using a lot of the given answers with no luck.

```
CodeSign /Users/XXXXXXXX/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XXXXXXXX-blligpejpeysabczydnolvooizok/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/XXXXXXXX.app
    cd /Users/XXXXXXXX/Documents/Development/Native/tomhais
    export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"

Signing Identity:     "iPhone Developer: XXXXXXX"
Provisioning Profile: "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: XXXXXX"
                      XXXXXXXX

    /usr/bin/codesign --force --sign XXXXXXXXX --entitlements /Users/XXXXXXX/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX/Build/Intermediates/tomhais.build/Debug-iphoneos/XXXXXX.build/XXXXXXX.app.xcent --timestamp=none /Users/XXXXXXX/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/tomhais.app

/Users/XXXXXXX/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/XXXXXXXX.app: code object is not signed at all
In subcomponent: /Users/XXXXXXXX/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/XXXXXXXX.app/0CeadLitir.png
Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1
```

I have tried the following:

1. Deleted my developer account and added it again
2. Deleted all the provisioning profiles and re-downloaded them
3. Checked the key-chain access to make sure that they use system
   defaults
4. Checked that my Code Signing is pulling in the right
   certificates
5. Deleted the image from resources/ removed it from `Build Phases / Copy Bundle Resources and added it again'
6. Rebooted the machine
7. Cursed at the machine

Any further ideas of what I might try?

[image]

Comment: Did you find any solution .please let me know i am also stucked in it

Answer (score 21):

What I found was that having a folder named "resources" in the application bundle will cause code sign to fail. This seems to be an undocumented consequence of some implementation detail of iOS apps or code signing, I think. An empty project with just a resources folder with one random file in it reproduced the issue.

I couldn't easily rename the folder with our shared codebase so my solution was to put my "resources" folder in a parent folder with a different name, and adjust the way our resource path was built.

Comment: That worked, having a folder named "resources" was my problem.  Holy crap, XCode is such a mess!  I've dug through so many threads on this topic and none of the other solutions worked.

Comment: Glad to be of help!

Comment: OMG, THANK YOU. I cannot believe I was cleaning the build folder before every single build and rebuilding every single file in the project for over a year just because of a folder named 'resources'.

Comment: Can someone please tell me where I can find this resource folder, I am stuck in this problem since yesterday

Comment: @pratteekshaurya If this is your issue, it would likely be a "copy bundle resources" build step in the project settings > targets > your app > build phases. The screenshot in this article shows the location in the UI: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1649/_index.html

Comment: Having a called in Tests/packageName/Resources caused this issue for me.

Comment: Same for Swift Package that has a resource that is called Resources mentioned ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, what resolved it was lock/unlock keychain login as described here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52628909/1104479)

Answer (score 0):

First, check your code have lots of useless variables and remove them, then   then x code top bar product -> clear and build the folder and run

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and spent about a day by trying all suggestions.

Finally, I have solved the problem.

1. Close Xcode.
2. Open "Keychain Access.app", find and remove all "Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority".
3. Login to developer.apple.com and remove development and distribution certificate.
4. Open Xcode again and check "Automatically manage signing". Then Xcode(should be 11.4.1 or later) will download renewed WWDR certificate automatically and generate development certificate.
5. Clean project and build.

Answer (score 0):

I was working with the `ARKit`, and the problem appears when I try to convert a `.dae` element into a `.scn` after that I try to compile but the non zero exit error appears.
I try everything above but nothing worked for me. But I notice that in the project inside the `art.scnassets` folder was my new file but without the `.snc` extension. 
So the solution was very simple, I just add the `.snc` to my file, I Clean My Build Folder from the Product menu in Xcode, I ran it again and that Works for me.