# react-native run-ios --device getting codesign error

Tags: iphone, react-native, build, react-native-ios

my react-native builds fine on xcode simulator and android simulator. However, whenever I try to build on my iphone, I get the following codesign error. When I build from xcode, the build succeeds without problem but nothing happens. When I build from command line, the following error occurs.

/Users/chooseongmin/Desktop/dustNotifier/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/dustNotifier.app: resource fork, Finder information, or similar detritus not allowed

Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code

** BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
        CodeSign /Users/chooseongmin/Desktop/dustNotifier/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/dustNotifier.app
(1 failure)

Answer (score 0):

You need an apple developer account and a registered device there so that Xcode can create a signing certificate for you. Go to [developer page](https://developer.apple.com/) create your account (if you didn't), select personal team at project general settings, connect your iphone, click on register device and run again.

Comment: I have both the account and registered iphone

Comment: have you tried this? [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52421999/xcode-10-command-codesign-failed-with-a-nonzero-exit-code]

Comment: I tried the keychain approach but it only worked the first time.. also, atm I am only using an Apple ID and not a dev account...shouldn't I still be able to test using xcode, simulator etc w/o getting this error?