# Command Code sign Failed with a nonzero exit code when building flutter app using Xcode (errSecInternalComponent)

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, signing

I am getting getting this error:

```
/Users/administrator/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-xxxxxxx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Runner.app/Frameworks/App.framework: errSecInternalComponent
```

When building a flutter app.

I found some hints that might be related to xattrs.

```
xattr -rc folder/to/sources
```

does not help.

I saw that when running new builds, there are lots of files with `com.apple.quarantine` attributes in my app's folder.

So I also

```
xattr -rc ~/development/flutter
```

After this step, the  `com.apple.quarantine` files stopped to appear, but I still get the same error.

I tried the possible solutions in https://medium.com/@ceyhunkeklik/how-to-fix-ios-application-code-signing-error-4818bd331327

My key / identity seems to be accessible. I also tried a restart and flutter clean.

EDIT:

I also cannot find any information about setting the debuglevel of the codesign binary - is that possible?

EDIT2: Now trying

[Xcode 10, Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52421999/xcode-10-command-codesign-failed-with-a-nonzero-exit-code)

Answer (score 3):

In my case code sign failing issue happened because of keeping project files on shared iCloud directory. I realized that after trying out all popular suggestions like `flutter clean` or xCode wizardry actions related to this issue, so I finally managed to re-create the project in local non-shared drive directory and the problem disappeared.

Comment: Late reply, but this fixed it for me.

Comment: You save my day. I use OneDrive in my case. Have no idea why this error occurs in the first place

Comment: How to check if the project files are on a shared iCloud directory?

Comment: @yardstick17 from official [Apple support doc](https://support.apple.com/en-en/guide/mac-help/mchl91854a7a/mac): On your Mac, select a folder or document in iCloud Drive, or open a document in an app that supports iCloud File Sharing.

Click the Share button  , then select Manage Shared Folder or Manage Shared File.

Perform one of the following actions.

Revoke access for all users. Click Stop Sharing.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix that by switching off "Automatically manage signing" and used a distribution certificate and profile which I had to create on the Apple developer website beforehand.

Comment: I am doing as you have said, but facing the same issue in the above question