# How to release app to my phone and not get "code object is not signed at all" "Failed with exit code 1"

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm new to ios app development. I've developed an app that loads fine into the xcode 12 simulator, on a simulated iphone 11.

I've now plugged in an iphone 6 device and am trying to run the app on there.

I'm trying the only settings xcode seems to allow me, which is:

```
Under 'signing and capabilities':
Automatically manage signing
Team - (my name (Personal Team))
Bundle identifier - the app I'm trying to release
Provisioning profile - xcode managed profile
Signing certificate - the certificate I generated by going to the Accounts -> Manage certificates and generating a developer certificate.
```

Under 'Build settings' under 'signing' I have:

```
Code signing Identity - iOS developer (I also tried apple development)
Code signing style - automatic
Development team - same team as above
Provisioning profile - automatic
```

I've been fiddling around with it for about 2 hours now and always getting the same error:

```
code object is not signed at all
```

and then finally

```
Failed with exit code 1
```

EDIT: Could it be anything to do with ios versions? The iphone 6 is running ios 12.4 and I think I saw somewhere that xcode is using sdk 14.0?

EDIT: I've created a test app and I get the same error.
It always seems to be with the swift libraries.

Comment: Check the deployment target of your app. If you created a new project, that is probably set to iOS 14 or 13, and you need to lower it to 12.4 to be able to run on your iPhone 6

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I found the solution - need to clear everything apple developer out of keychain and let it re-download.

Answer (score 0):

OK, after trying the literally 20 or so answers in various threads, I finally got it to work. Hopefully, this will help someone.

1. Deleted my apple account from Xcode
2. Closed Xcode
3. Went into keychain login items and deleted everything that seemed to be to do with ios development including certificates etc.
4. Reopened Xcode and re-added my account.

I guess everything gets redownloaded and somehow Xcode had got confused.

Disclaimer - I can't guarantee you won't delete something important from the keychain, but this worked for me - finally after about 5 hours of mucking about.

Thanks to this answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/55369796/832200