# Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code Flutter ipa file

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, cocoapods

I am getting this error only when trying to build an ipa file with a Flutter app. There is no build error for any simulator on Xcode.
I downgraded XCode to 13.2.1, reinstalled Cocoapods, tried flutter clean, build install only and most of the other treads solutions. Any help would be awesome.

Flutter (Channel stable, 3.0.5, on macOS 12.5.1 Darwin.arm),

Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.2.1)

Here is my ipa build error:

> Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Here is my flutter build iOS error:

> Failed to build iOS app
> Error output from Xcode build:
> ↳
> objc[12481]: Class AMSupportURLConnectionDelegate is implemented in both /usr/lib/libamsupport.dylib (0x1f234b808) and
> /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x107fe02c8). One of the two will be used. Which
> one is undefined.
> objc[12481]: Class AMSupportURLSession is implemented in both /usr/lib/libamsupport.dylib (0x1f234b858) and
> /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x107fe0318). One of the two will be used. Which
> one is undefined.
> objc[12481]: Class AppleTypeCRetimerRestoreInfoHelper is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x1f234b620) and
> /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x107fe0598). One of the two will be used. Which
> one is undefined.
> objc[12481]: Class AppleTypeCRetimerFirmwareAggregateRequestCreator is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x1f234b670) and
> /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x107fe05e8). One of the two will be used. Which
> one is undefined.
> objc[12481]: Class AppleTypeCRetimerFirmwareRequestCreator is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x1f234b6c0) and
> /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x107fe0638). One of the two will be used. Which
> one is undefined.
> objc[12481]: Class ATCRTRestoreInfoFTABFile is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x1f234b710) and
> /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x107fe0688). One of the two will be used. Which
> one is undefined.
> objc[12481]: Class AppleTypeCRetimerFirmwareCopier is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x1f234b760) and
> /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x107fe06d8). One of the two will be used. Which
> one is undefined.
> objc[12481]: Class ATCRTRestoreInfoFTABSubfile is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x1f234b7b0) and
> /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x107fe0728). One of the two will be used. Which
> one is undefined.
> ** BUILD FAILED **

Lastly the --verbose output:

> Encountered error while building for device.
> #0      throwToolExit
> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
> #1      _BuildIOSSubCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/build_ios.dart:374:7)
>
> #2      FlutterCommand.run. (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1183:27)
>
> #3      AppContext.run. (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
>
> #4      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:209:13)
>
> #5      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand. (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:281:9)
>
> #6      AppContext.run. (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
>
> #7      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:229:5)
>
> #8      run.. (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:62:9)
>
> #9      AppContext.run. (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
>
> #10     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:94:3)

Answer (score 0):

solved after 10 hours by deleting and re-downloading certificates

**KeyChain Access - Certificates - Delete all about your project -
Go to developer.apple - Find your certificate and download - Go to Xcode - Signing&Capabilities - Revoke - Clean Build and done**

thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/60905124/15837005