# How to Resolve "Command CodeSign failed" Error in Visual Studio Code for iOS Builds?

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode

I hope you're all doing well. I'm encountering a perplexing issue while trying to build my iOS app in the iOS emulator. When I attempt to build the app using Visual Studio Code, I'm getting the following error:

[THIS ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jka94.jpg)

`Uncategorized (Xcode): Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code`

However, **when I use Xcode itself to build the app, everything works just fine.** I've noticed that other community members have faced a similar issue, and I've read through their suggestions and tried several of them, but none have helped in my case.

**What's particularly puzzling to me is that Xcode builds the app successfully, yet when attempting the same with Visual Studio Code, it fails with the "Command CodeSign failed" error.** This inconsistency has me scratching my head, and I'm eager to resolve it.

Xcode Version: Version 15.0 beta 5 (15A5209g)

I've already tried several solutions that I found online, such as cleaning the build folder, restarting both Xcode and VS Code, and even rebooting my Mac, but none of them have helped when using VS Code. It's quite inconvenient to have to switch to Xcode every time I want to build.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem or have any insights into what might be causing this issue? I'd greatly appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to resolve it, especially if you have encountered and resolved this issue yourself.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Did you add any assets in your project? (mp3, wav, etc) Or any other with a file extension? If yes, check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52421999/xcode-10-command-codesign-failed-with-a-nonzero-exit-code

Comment: I have added assets that have svg images in them. I did try the suggested solution but didn't help .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xcode 10, Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52421999/xcode-10-command-codesign-failed-with-a-nonzero-exit-code)

Comment: Unfortunately non of the solution helped in resolving the error.